# Else If statement for ACF

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to build in a feature using ACF where a user picks an option to have the hero image change to one of three options. 1) A static hero image 2) A youtube video 3) A mp4 on loop. I have the backend end set up with a conditional to show which one depending on the option, however, I want the user to be able to select an option and have that option appear over the others. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
if(get_field('hero_video', 'options') ) {
 $headervideo = get_field( 'hero_video', 'options' );
 echo '<div class="headervideo">' . $headervideo . '</div>';

else if ( get_field( 'hero_upload', 'options' ) ) {
     $headerupload = get_field( 'hero_upload', 'options' );
     echo '<div class="hero-video" data-vide-bg="mp4: ' . 
       $headerupload . '" data-vide-options="loop: true, muted: true">
</div>';
 else
     ( get_field( 'header_image', 'options' ) ){
     $headerimage = get_field( 'header_image', 'options' );
     echo '<img class="headerimage" src ="' . $headerimage['url'] . 
'" alt="' . $headerimage['alt'] . '" />';
 }
?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Before I did this, I had just if statements. But if the user left an image in the image selection box, it would stay up. I'm trying to avoid that with this.  The current error I get is "syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)" on line 6.

Comment: This question is not about WP but about PHP. The error message explains itself. You have an unexpected else-statement on line 6, because you forgot to close the if with a } on the line before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing curly brackets and another syntax. This should help:

```
<?php
if(get_field('hero_video', 'option') ) {
     $headervideo = get_field( 'hero_video', 'option' );
     echo '<div class="headervideo">' . $headervideo . '</div>';
} elseif ( get_field( 'hero_upload', 'options' ) ) {
     $headerupload = get_field( 'hero_upload', 'option' );
     echo '<div class="hero-video" data-vide-bg="mp4: ' . 
     $headerupload . '" data-vide-options="loop: true, muted: true">
</div>';
} else {
     get_field( 'header_image', 'option' );
     $headerimage = get_field( 'header_image', 'option' );
     echo '<img class="headerimage" src ="' . $headerimage['url'] . 
'" alt="' . $headerimage['alt'] . '" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: This works great, however, I still need to delete the media then press update, then upload an image and press update. Is there a way to expand this to display the selected content of a conditional logic select field? So if I select Image, it'll display that over a video?

Comment: If I'm understanding your goal correctly, allowing the user to select multiple options, all you need to do is make 3 separate "if" statements. Change "elseif" and "else" to just "if" and then any of the 3 that are available will be shown in the page. From there you will need to adjust divs and css accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The user has a drop down select that allows them to choose three options. Depending on the option they choose (image, video gif, or video mp4) I want that to show. As of now, they can choose any of the three, but if an image is still present after they choose, lets say video gif, the image will appear over the video.

Comment: So are you wanting them to only be able to choose one - image, video gif, or video mp4? If so, you could use a Flexible Layout ACF field and set it to maximum of 1 row, so they are forced to choose one of the three.

Comment: Thanks for taking so much time with on this. Currently they can only choose one, I would just like it to show which ever selection they have, on the front end. Does that make sense? So this is for a banner image. When they select Image from the ACF dropdown they can add an image. Hit update and boom done. However, they can go back and add a video by selecting Video MP4.  But the issue is, is that the image stays over the video and doesn't replace it.

Comment: Gotcha. You need to set it up as a single field - that way whatever they select will overwrite whatever they had selected previously. Create a new Flexible Content field, maybe called "hero". Set up a layout for image, a separate layout for video gif, separate layout for video mp4. Then set minimum and maximum layouts to 1. In this way, if they switch from one type to another, the old value gets completely overwritten and you do not end up with image + video. Alternatively a Repeater would work if the first field is a radio-button choice of img, gif, mp4, and the other fields are conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Plus Syntax Errors, you type `options` instead of `option`.

this code should work:

```
<?php
$headervideo = get_field( 'hero_video', 'option' );
$headerupload = get_field( 'hero_upload', 'option' );
$headerimage = get_field( 'header_image', 'option' );

if($headervideo) {
 echo '<div class="headervideo">' . $headervideo . '</div>';
}
elseif($headerupload) {
     echo '<div class="hero-video" data-vide-bg="mp4: ' . 
       $headerupload . '" data-vide-options="loop: true, muted: true">
</div>';
}
else{
     echo '<img class="headerimage" src ="' . $headerimage['url'] . 
'" alt="' . $headerimage['alt'] . '" />';
 }
?>
```